# Lock workspace to extract exact same crops .tifs from different wms raster layers

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, extract

I am trying to lock a zone into qgis to extract exactly the same crop of raster images coming from around 20 different wms layers one by one.

I can  make it one by one but it is very difficult not to move and change the scale and the magnifier.

I want to restrict the zone with a square polygon and always extract images inside this polygon.

Is it also possible to download the rasters?

I mean make offline only this zone of the wms layers.

---

@Kasper’s answer seems a good idea but for now it only works with downloaded raster layer and not with a wms server

here is the error log :

Process returned error code 1
ERROR 4: `contextualWMSLegend=0&crs=EPSG:31370&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/png&layers=Urbis:Ortho2014&styles&url=http://geoservices-urbis.irisnet.be/geoserver/ows' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.

Answer (score 0):

Create a polygon layer with the desired Polygon.
Then use the Processing Toolbox : `Clip raster by Extent` as a batch process.

Set it to clip all your raster layers, based on the polygon layer Extent:

[image]